# kineticjs - setImage - compress/reduce image quality before drawing to stage

Tags: compression, kineticjs

I have the following jsfiddle which he an existing image with a button that when clicked will change the image src randomly from an array.

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/GpSbd/7/

Some of these images will be very large, is it possible to reduce or compress the image file down before it does setImage and draws it onto the stage as i will eventually be uploading the images onto our server so want them to be as small as possible

```
// CHANGE IMAGE FUNCTION
$('#changeImage').on("click", function(){ 
    var newImage = new Image();
    var img = layer.get('#Image1')[0];
    newImage.onload = function() {

                    <-- CAN I COMPRESS IT AT THIS STAGE? -->

        img.setImage(newImage);
        layer.draw();
    };
    var random = pictures[Math.floor(Math.random()*pictures.length)];
    newImage.src = random;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have the image urls saved in your pictures[] array.

Just save that url (`random`) on your server and not the image itself.

This cuts your storage size by 20-100 times.

If the server needs to temporarily use the image, the server can use the url to fetch it.